# How to replicate import.meta.url to get the relative path in a non type="module" script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the relative path to the current script when the script is a "classic script" (when the `type` is not set as `type=module`).

```html
<script src="./scripts/foo.js"></script>
```

I'd like to be able to get the current relative path to that script.

I have tried getting the URL from the `document.currentScript.src` but this doesn't factor in if the page has a `<base href="./foo">` and I am not sure if there are other modifiers that affect the path.

Is there a comprehensive way to resolve the relative or absolute path to the current script?

Comment: Can't you get rid of base yourself?  That's what I would do, since base is probably a known constant.

Comment: I am not in control of the source code so I cannot change the base tag. I'm writing a bundler and part of the shipped wrapping code needs to know how to find dynamic bundles relative to the current script.

Comment: I'm not saying "get rid of the base" as in "remove the base URL".  Remove it from the URL obtained from document.currentScript.src.  Remove the base.  Whatever is left, is the URL you need.